# Mask over the image view Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift3, swift5

I have been trying to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39611768/2829540) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525645/masked-uivisualeffectview-does-not-work-on-ios-10) using Swift 5.2
I only see the blurred image and the mask is not appearing. Can someone point me what I am missing there or how to convert it to Swift 5 from Swift 3?

This is a playground code.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let generalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
let containerView = UIView(frame: generalFrame)
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView

let parentView = UIView(frame: generalFrame)
containerView.addSubview(parentView)
let url = URL(string: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/168066/pexels-photo-168066-large.jpeg")
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!);
let imageView = UIImageView(frame:parentView.bounds)
imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

let maskView = UIView(frame:parentView.bounds)
maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
maskView.layer.mask = {() -> CALayer in
    var  roundedRect = CGRect (
        x: 0.0,
        y: 0.0,
        width: parentView.bounds.size.width * 0.5,
        height: parentView.bounds.size.width * 0.5
    );
    roundedRect.origin.x = parentView.frame.size.width / 2 - roundedRect.size.width / 2;
    roundedRect.origin.y = parentView.frame.size.height / 2 - roundedRect.size.height / 2;
    let cornerRadius = roundedRect.size.height / 2.0;
    let path = UIBezierPath(rect:parentView.bounds)
    let croppedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
    path.append(croppedPath)
    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath;
    maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
    return maskLayer
}()

let blurView = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurView)

effectView.frame = generalFrame
effectView.mask = maskView

parentView.addSubview(imageView)
parentView.addSubview(effectView)
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working. The fix was to apply mask to UIVisualEffectView:

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
effectView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let generalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
let containerView = UIView(frame: generalFrame)
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView

let parentView = UIView(frame: generalFrame)
containerView.addSubview(parentView)

let url = URL(string: "https://static.pexels.com/photos/168066/pexels-photo-168066-large.jpeg")
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!);
let imageView = UIImageView(frame:parentView.bounds)

imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

var roundedRect = CGRect (
    x: 0.0,
    y: 0.0,
    width: parentView.bounds.size.width * 0.5,
    height: parentView.bounds.size.width * 0.5
);
roundedRect.origin.x = parentView.frame.size.width / 2 - roundedRect.size.width / 2;
roundedRect.origin.y = parentView.frame.size.height / 2 - roundedRect.size.height / 2;
let cornerRadius = roundedRect.size.height / 2.0;
let path = UIBezierPath(rect:parentView.bounds)
let croppedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
path.append(croppedPath)
path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath;
maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd

let blurView = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurView)
effectView.frame = generalFrame
effectView.layer.mask = maskLayer

parentView.addSubview(imageView)
parentView.addSubview(effectView)
```

[image]